# ERROR ITMS-90578 when upload ipa

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is there anyone know what is following error message means for?

> ERROR ITMS-90578: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The UPP provisioning
>   profile included in the bundle com.xxxx.mybundle [My-Target] is
>   disallowed."

[image]

My app already had been released for about 6 month, and this happens when I want to send my new version for apple review...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the answer...

Use same AppleID that create certification and .p12 to upload my ipa resolve this issue.